# how to see the query processed with php PDO? !

Tags: php, pdo

I'm preparing my sql statements and binding parameters to it and if something  goes wrong i catch them in a catch block. But, i want to see which query i processed. So i extended the PDO class (found it on the internet , not exactly sure what i'm doing or where the ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS is really for. So this is the code of the extention:

```
class PDOTester extends PDO {
public function __construct($dsn, $username = null, $password = null, $driver_options = array()) {
    parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $driver_options);
    $this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, array('PDOStatementTester', array($this)));
}
}
class PDOStatementTester extends PDOStatement {
protected $connection;

protected function __construct(PDO $connection)
{
    $this->connection = $connection;
}

public function execute() {
    try {
        parent::execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->errorInfo[3] = $this->queryString;
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($this);
        var_dump($this->connection);
        echo '</pre>';
        throw $e;
    }
}
}
```

But, here comes the problem, i used named parameters to bind values to it, but when i see the SQl query then i see the named parameters and not the values!

For example, i use it like:

```
try { 
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES (:column1, :column2)"; 
$stmt = $db->preapre($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':column1', $column1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':column2', $column2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
echo $e->errorInfo[3];
}
```

But then i see as values :column1, :column2, instead of the actual variables!
Can please someone help me out (for example provide a better modification of the extension i use)?

PHP Version 5.2.17, MySQL version 5.0.92

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to see the actual query when using prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Your best option would be to turn MySQL's general log option.
Run the following in MySQL terminal (or any other preferred program / app you use to control MySQL)

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = ON;
SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'path_to_file.log';
```

Run your query, inspect the file.

Comment: Superb! Thnx, that was very useful!

Comment: If there is a syntax error or missing column/field in the query (which is one of the likely reasons for a PDOException being thrown), is it still going to log those? (partly for my curiosity, partly for general clarification)

Comment: It'll log anything that actually gets to MySQL. If you invoke a nonexisting function that throws a PDOException (assuming there is such error implementation), it won't log it. It will log failed queries in transaction, malformed queries and so on - basically anything reaching the MySQL daemon.

Answer (score 0):

They *really* didn't need to extend the PDO class to do what they did. Simply create a new instance then add (or remove) that attribute after creation rather than during.

That being said, there's a built-in way of outputting the debug information regarding a statement, and that's using  [`PDOStatement->debugDumpParams`](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php). This won't let you see the compiled version (that's done database-side for databases that support it) but it will let you see both the query and that bound parameters easily.

A note of caution, don't enable this on a live system. It could give attackers of your website a big clue into how your system is set up and what they can do it take over (and destroy or otherwise ruin).

Comment: Thnx for the function! But that still doesn't output the values of the parameters.

Comment: ... Huh. So it doesn't. I misread the examples on that page. I guess this is why Zend's Db adapter does its own encapsulation of all those aspects.